# How might a bash.exe appear in system32 of Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash

I just discovered that running `bash` on one of my Windows machines launches a bash terminal. Apparently this is running a bash.exe in Windows/system32. I'm assuming Win10 does not by default come with a bash interpreter

How did this bash.exe get there? I don't remember installing anything that would place that there. The weird thing is that when I launch bash, the username I see is not my Windows username...so I'm pretty confused.

I haven't installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux, and while I do have git on this machine, launching git bash shows me a different username than the one I see when I run `bash`, so I'm guessing this isn't git's doing.

Any ideas so to what might've caused this situation?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the application that is launched

Comment: This question is clear as a day: the guy discovered `bash.exe` in the `system32` directory and wonders how it got there. I got exactly the same treatment here when asked my only ever question in this SO of super-duper-hyper-blooper-users who allow questions from Einsteins only. If you have a Windows question, ask in `r/Windows11` (or 10). The answer: `bash.exe` is installed as part of WSL, the optional Windows Subsystem for Linux. Perfectly safe, runs Linux commands in the default WSL distro. Mind Linux/Windows full path roots; relative paths on the same Windows drive letter are always OK.